# Translate Curl to R programming POST function

Tags: r, curl

I am trying to translate this code into R programming:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "X-IBM-Client-Id:YOUR_CLIENT_ID" -H "X-IBM-Client-Secret:YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET" -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" https://api.ibm.com/watsonanalytics/run/data/v1/datasets -d '{ "description" :"1234" , "name" :"1234" }'
```

But when i tried, it gives me an Unauthorized error.

Here it is the code I am using:

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
httpPOST("https://api.ibm.com/watsonanalytics/run/data/v1/datasets",
     content= c("description"="Test1",
                          "name"="Test1"),
     .opts = list(httpheader = c('Content-Type' = 'application/json', 
                                 'Accept' = 'application/json',
                                 'X-IBM-Client-Secret' = '123', 
                                 'X-IBM-Client-Id' = '123',
                                 'Authorization: Bearer'="")))
```

I really appreciate your help
Thank you

Comment: It is from RCurl library

Comment: It's good practice to include any libraries you're using in the question .

Comment: Thank you, I also added the other library I am using.